# How to query a database from my Flask python app?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, web-applications

So far I have successfully connected my code to the MariaDB database I want to query:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash
import mysql.connector
from datetime import date
import mariadb

app = Flask(__name__)

conn = mariadb.connect(host='IP', port= 3306, user='user', password='password', database='myDatabase')

cursor = conn.cursor()

result = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return result
    return render_template('index.html')
    
# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

How do I get a query to show up on my HTML page of this web app?

Comment: You need put the result data in simple python object, like list or a dictionary, and then pass it to the template to render.

Comment: better find some tutorial for Flask - you will have all answers much faster.

Comment: `return render_template('index.html', data=result.fetchall())` and in `HTML` you can use `data` with `for`-loop to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get it in any tutorial.

---

You have to send result to `render_template` as argument

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    results = result.fetchall() # get all rows 
    return render_template('index.html', data=results)
```

and next you can use name `data` in `HTML` to display it.

```html
{{ data }}
```

You may use `for`-loop in template to format it.

```html
<tabel>
{% for row in data %}
<tr>
    {% for item in row %}
      <td>{{ item }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

---

In `render_template` you can use any name - ie. `all_values=data` - and use `{{ all_values }}` in `HTML`